# Select & Group on UserID where Transaction Type fits a specific order and within 30 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Have a table in our SQL Server 2008 R2 database where we store TransactionID, TimeStamp, TransactionType, UserID, and other info.

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransactionRecords](
    [TransactionID] [float] NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [TransactionType] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [UserID] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)`

```
INSERT INTO TransactionRecords ( TransactionID, TimeStamp, TransactionType, UserID) VALUES
(3211, '2014-09-01 14:08:54.000', 'OnlineTrial', '00E235420CE9FD33'), 
(3212, '2014-09-01 14:28:19.000', 'OnlineOrder', '00E235420CE9FD33'), 
(3213, '2014-09-01 14:29:00.000', 'NewsletterSubscribe', '31E4E29230BFA615'), 
(3214, '2014-09-01 14:34:50.000', 'OnlineTrial', '2D37174DD60F450B'), 
(3215, '2014-09-01 14:44:44.000', 'OnlineOrder', '2D580670019B61F6'), 
(3216, '2014-09-01 14:54:22.000', 'NewsletterSubscribe', '376C5DF69356616E'), 
(3217, '2014-09-01 15:03:06.000', 'OnlineTrial', '31E4E29230BFA615'), 
(3218, '2014-09-01 15:27:01.000', 'OnlineOrder', '31E4E29230BFA615'), 
(3219, '2014-09-01 15:33:00.000', 'NewsletterSubscribe', '130F764A98409EF4'), 
(3220, '2014-09-01 15:42:00.000', 'OnlineTrial', '0417546E0D518432'), 
(3221, '2014-09-01 16:18:50.000', 'OnlineOrder', '05E4EB4E47C756B6'), 
(3222, '2014-09-01 16:55:40.000', 'OnlineOrder', '1B9FEBB7FD029625'), 
(3223, '2014-09-01 17:32:30.000', 'OnlineOrder', '061310EE4F20E3EA'), 
(3224, '2014-09-01 18:01:20.000', 'OnlineTrial', '061310EE4F20E3EA'), 
(3225, '2014-09-01 18:46:10.000', 'NewsletterSubscribe', '144937298097C9D4')`
```

What I would like to do is query so that I return the transaction IDs of users where they are logged as an OnlineTrial and then an OnlineOrder within a 30 minute window of the TimeStamp.

Right now my query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[TransactionID]
  ,a.[TimeStamp]
  ,a.[TransactionType]
  ,a.[UserID]
FROM [Adhoc].[dbo].[TransactionRecords] a
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Adhoc].[dbo].[TransactionRecords] b
ON a.UserID = b.UserID
WHERE DATEDIFF(MI, a.timestamp, b.timestamp) <= 30
AND a.TransactionID <> b.TransactionID
AND (a.TransactionType = 'OnlineTrial'
OR a.TransactionType = 'OnlineOrder')
ORDER BY a.UserID, a.TimeStamp
```

The ideal query just returns transactions 3211, 3212, 3217, & 3218
But my query still returns results where the User took an OnlineOrder and then OnlineTrial (IDs 3223 & 3224)

Comment: (1) What version of SQL Server?  (2) You should include sample data, desired results, and a sample query.  This is definitely a forum where a picture is *not* worth 1000 words.

Comment: @jpw even better, a `create table` and `insert` script

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just updated, thanks.

Comment: @Laurence Just included scripts, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists` to match the necessary rows:

```
select
    *
from
    dbo.TransactionRecords t1
where
    t1.transactiontype = 'OnlineTrial' and
    exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            dbo.TransactionRecords t2
        where
            t1.UserID = t2.UserID and
            t2.transactiontype = 'OnlineOrder' and
            datediff(mi, t1.Timestamp, t2.Timestamp) between 0 and 30
    )
union all
select
    *
from
    dbo.TransactionRecords t1
where
    t1.transactiontype = 'OnlineOrder' and
    exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            dbo.TransactionRecords t2
        where
            t1.UserID = t2.UserID and
            t2.transactiontype = 'OnlineTrial' and
            datediff(mi, t2.Timestamp, t1.Timestamp) between 0 and 30
    )
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/611db/5)

Answer (score 0):

Should be a simple JOIN to itself based on the user ID and explicit transaction type reference.  The outer WHERE only gets the online trials... The JOIN is explicitly looking for the same user, but online ORDERs.. by ANDing the time difference should be what you need.

```
select
      tr.transactionid,
      tr.timestamp,
      tr.transactionType,
      tr.UserID
   from
      transactionRecords tr
         JOIN transactionRecords trOrder
            on tr.UserID = trOrder.UserID
           AND trOrder = 'OnlineOrder'
           AND DATEDIFF(MI, tr.timestamp, trOrder.timestamp) <= 30
   where
      tr.transactionType = 'OnlineTrial'
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for both order rows, but where the sequential process is OnlineTrial and then OnlineOrder by the same UserID within 30 minutes.  That Join only gets me the orders and not necessarily in that order either.

Comment: @TroySteen, I'm starting with Online Trial and only then looking for Orders... based on those trials.  If the DATEDIFF function is backwards from anticipated (30 minutes), then maybe change via DATEDIFF( MI, trOrder.timestamp, tr.timestamp ) <= 30.